# What is a difference between sar %ifutil and nicstat %Util?

Tags: linux, network-interface

[nicstat](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GCIDt.png)

[sar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3DaCH.png)

the first is `nicstat 3`
the second is `sar -n DEV 3`
why eth0 network interface util is diffrent between sar %ifutil and nicstat %util

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are using an old version sar, which ifutil is wrong for 10Gib network interface.

https://github.com/sysstat/sysstat/issues/75